# How would I let my main method access the paint method I created inside Applet?

Tags: java

The paint class with hello is what I'd like to use the main variables in. How would I do so? I would like to move the variables so I can make a conditional to draw strings when the correct or incorrect letter is guess.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class testing extends Applet
{


    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        JFrame jp1 = new JFrame();
        testing a =new testing ();
        jp1.getContentPane().add(a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp1.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jp1.setVisible(false);

        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\s612153\\Documents\\Java files\\words.data"));
        ArrayList <String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList <String> arrayinco = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList <String> arraycorr = new ArrayList<String>();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        int variable = random.nextInt(c) + 1;

        for(int x = 0; x < c; x++)
        {
            String string = scanner.next();
            arraylist.add(string);
        } 

        String word = arraylist.get(variable);
        word = word.toUpperCase();
        out.println(word);
        int length = word.length();
        ArrayList <String> arrayundr = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            arrayundr.add("_ ");
        }

        out.println(arrayundr);


        int attempts = 7;
        int var = 0;


        for(int x = var; x < attempts; x = x)
        {
            String guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter: ");
        char Char = guess.charAt(0);
        Char = Character.toUpperCase(Char);
            if(word.indexOf(Char) >= 0)
            {
                String let = Character.toString(Char);
                int gerb = word.indexOf(Char);
                int kirby = word.indexOf(Char, gerb + 1);
                out.println("That is correct");
                arraycorr.add(let);
                arrayundr.set(gerb, let);
                out.println("WORD: " + arrayundr);
                attempts = attempts + 1;

            }
            else if(word.indexOf(Char) != 0)
            {
                String bet = Character.toString(Char);
                out.println("incorrect!");
                arrayinco.add(bet);
                x = x + 1;
            }

        }




        out.println(arrayinco);
    }
```

The paint class that I would like to use my main variables in!!!

```
     public void paint (Graphics g)
    {

        g.drawString("hello",40,30);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to make the string a property of the testing class, which can then be set using the handle you have on the applet, e.g.:

```
public class testing extends Applet {
    private String message = "";

    public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
    {
        JFrame jp1 = new JFrame();
        testing a =new testing ();
        // ..
        a.message = "Hello";
        // ..
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(message,40,30);
    }
}
```